# What is wrong with this sentence? "Becoming a leader is a very predictable process."

Tags: grammar, verbs

Something about this sentence sounds awkward but I cannot figure out what it is.

> "Becoming a leader is a very predictable process."
>
> "Being a leader is a very predictable process."

Does anyone have suggestions? I use a parallel structure in my paper that involves a lot of sentences that start with "Being a leader."

Comment: "becoming" indicates a process, while "being" indicates a state. I think the sentence is fine with "becoming", though not with "being".

Comment: @Gustavson _It is the process of becoming a leader be over when the process of being a leader begins._ Is it correct to use a subjunctive in such a manner?

Comment: @MvLog You can't use subjunctive but present simple there: *It is **when** the process of becoming a leader **is** over **that** the process of being a leader begins.* (Here "being a leader" is equivalent to "acting as a leader".)

Comment: Both the sentences are fine. There are absolutely no grammar issues. However, with regard to content, being is not a process. Being a leader is hard; Becoming a leader requires a process. I would avoid IS.

Comment: I agree that both sentences are grammatical, but only the first makes sense *semantically*.  In addition, if you say something is a "predictable process" you will be expected to define why.

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatical, but it is also awkward. Get rid of "very" and the sentence will sound a lot better. As stated in Gustavson's comment, you can also change to "very" to "highly" to make the sentence sound better.

> Becoming a leader is a predictable process.
>
> Becoming a leader is a highly predictable process.

The second sentence in your question is hard to understand as several comments have said, because "becoming" is a process but "being" is a state.

Comment: "highly" would sound better than "very". It all comes down to the process-state distinction I made in  the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what **tense** you are talking about.

- Past tense: You should say '**becoming**' as it is talking about what has **happened in the past**, somewhat as similar to being a process.
- Now: If you are talking as if it was **happening now,** you should most definitely say '**being**' however this sounds a bit awkward due to the **shortness** of the sentence. You may want to add some more **syllables or adjectives** to it to make the sound of the sentence **flow** more.